# Stored a file directory in notepad but couldn't open it when I use Java to reference it

Tags: java

I would like to store the directory of the file that I want to open with my GUI into a notepad. I am able to read the file correctly but when I want to reference it, I could not open the file.
My code:

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
File sharepoint = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "SharePoint");

try {
    File file= new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/File.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        str.append(line);
        str.append("\n");
    }
    fr.close();
    // Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(sharepoint + "/Open Project Transition Check - Doc/Project Status Summary/a.xlsb"));
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println(str.toString());
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(str.toString()));

} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please check that you have SharePoint access, contact your admin for more assistance", "Access error",  JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    // Logger.getLogger(HPform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Plese provide more information and example for above code snippet. What file you want to open? Also provide content of the file.

Comment: @kai hi, could you try to change the `File` argument into this `"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\File.txt"`? and see what happen

Comment: Nope. Not helping but thanks.

Comment: @kai, then can you try to print out the exception rather than hiding it? try something like `ex.printStackTrace()` and post the result.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: C:\Users\user\SharePoint\Open Project Transition Check - Doc\Project Status Summary\a.xlsb
 doesn't exist.

Comment: Which does not make sense because if I were to use the normal convention, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your problem

```
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    str.append(line);
    str.append("\n"); <-- what this new line for? if it's not used, delete it
}
```

even if your txt file has only one file. the problem will still persist as that is not a valid argument for opening file (your end result will be `C:\Users\user\SharePoint\Open Project Transition Check - Doc\Project Status Summary\a.xlsb\n`)